# How to split a git repository into two separate repositories

Tags: git, github, cmake, repository

Right now I have a (C++) GitHub repository with this layout:

```
my-library/
  src/
  CMakeLists.txt # Builds into a library
tests/
  src/
  CMakeLists.txt # Builds into an executable
CMakeLists.txt
README.md
```

I just want to split this repository into two:

- one that contains exactly the `my-library` folder,
- one that contains the `tests` folder that will contain a submodule of `my-library` (not the problem for now).

I cant find a way to achive this without erasing the git history.
There is only the main branch in the repository that I want to split.

I have seen [this article](https://bornsql.ca/blog/how-do-i-merge-a-small-part-of-a-git-repo-into-another-repo/) to split to repositories but it doesn't work for me because it only erase the other directories and leaves the content of my library into the `my-library` folder: it refractors to:

```
my-library/
  src/
  CMakeLists.txt # Builds into a library
# Other folders were deleted
```

However I want it to look like this:

```
src/
CMakeLists.txt # Builds into a library
```

**That's the point of my question**

Comment: That should be it. I'm checking

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you want to split a git repository into two separate repositories.

You can try that by creating a clone of the original reposit

```
git clone https://github.com/<username>/<original-repo>
```

Navigate into the cloned repository:

```
cd <original-repo>
```

Create a new, empty repository for the "my-library" project:

```
git init ../my-library-repo
```

Move the "my-library" directory into the new repository:

```
mv my-library ../my-library-repo
```

Use git filter-repo to rewrite history and keep only the "my-library" directory:

```
cd ../my-library-repo
git filter-repo --path my-library --subdirectory-filter my-library
```

Navigate back to the original repository:

```
cd ../<original-repo>
```

Create a new repository for the "tests" project:

```
git init ../tests-repo
```

Push the "my-library" repository to GitHub:

```
cd ../my-library-repo
git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/<my-library-repo>
git push -u origin main
```

In the "tests" repository, add the "my-library" repository as a submodule:

```
cd ../tests-repo
git submodule add https://github.com/<username>/<my-library-repo> my-library
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly I already solved it with the above comment.